# VBA – Using One Click Event for Multiple Toggle Buttons

Tags: vba, events, click, activex, togglebutton

I have a whole bunch of toggle buttons on 1 sheet, and I want them to have identical `_click` events. Is there a way I can do this without writing a new `_click` function for every single button?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you might have to do soemthing for each one anyway. I would put the basic code in a function and have each individual click event call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way would be to use a class module to control the events for your controls...

1) Insert a class module (VBE > Insert > Class Module).

2) In the Properties window under Name, enter clsToggleButtonGroup.

3) Copy and paste the following code into the code module for the class...

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ToggleButton As MSForms.ToggleButton

Private Sub ToggleButton_Click()
    MsgBox ToggleButton.Caption
    'do stuff
    '
    '
End Sub
```

4) In a regular module (VBE > Insert > Module), copy and paste the following code...

```
Option Explicit

Public colToggleButtons As New Collection

Sub AddToggleButtonsToClass()

    Dim OleObj As OLEObject
    Dim cToggleButton As clsToggleButtonGroup

    For Each OleObj In Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects 'change the sheet name accordingly
        If TypeName(OleObj.Object) = "ToggleButton" Then
            Set cToggleButton = New clsToggleButtonGroup
            Set cToggleButton.ToggleButton = OleObj.Object
            colToggleButtons.Add cToggleButton
        End If
    Next OleObj

End Sub
```

5) Then, run AddToggleButtonsToClass.

Comment: I tried something along those lines but it wouldn't d anything. I think I read something about it not working if I do it in a worksheet module, and that it has to be in a regular module. Is that right?

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine.  With your ToggleButtons located on a worksheet, you'll have the code for the click event in a class module, and the code adding the ToggleButtons to your class in a regular module.  When inserting a class module, don't forget to re-name it, as I've described in my post.

Comment: Im getting Run Time Error 424: Object Required on the line `colToggleButtons.Add cToggleButton`...

Comment: Did you declare colToggleButtons at the top of your regular module as `Public colToggleButtons As New Collection`?

Comment: Nope. Thanks. So now I am at where I was before. It compiles with no errors, but nothing happens when I click the buttons.

Comment: Once you've set it up as I've described, you need to run the macro called `AddToggleButtonsToClass`.  Did you run it?

Comment: In my code, I referenced Sheet1.  Did you change the name to the sheet containing your togglebuttons?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151747/discussion-between-ari-levisohn-and-domenic).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: nope.

Longer answer: nope. *But* you don't have to copy/paste the whole entire logic for every handler. Just extract that logic into its own `Private` method, and invoke it from the handlers.

```
Private Sub RunToggleButtonLogic()
    'do stuff
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    RunToggleButtonLogic
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    RunToggleButtonLogic
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()
    RunToggleButtonLogic
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton4_Click()
    RunToggleButtonLogic
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton5_Click()
    RunToggleButtonLogic
End Sub

...
```

The reason for this is that VBA is COM, and COM events work with interfaces (like Java), not delegates (like C#, or VB.NET) - so you can't "assign" a handler to an event, it simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: Man I was literally typing out a comment that says just this (not spelled out of course).

Comment: Turns out there is a way. See Domenic's answer.